# How to use custom cordova plugin in ionic project?

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework

I have got a simple custom cordova plugin from here(https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-hello), which can output a string, but how can I use this plugin in my ionic project after I have installed it.

Javascript interface of the plugin like this:

```
module.exports = {
greet: function (name, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "Hello", "greet", [name]);
}};
```

And I invoke javascript interface like this way:

```
window.plugins.hello.greet("World", success, failure);
```

But it doesn't work,and I get error as following:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.plugins.hello')
```

Comment: Did I miss something in the project? And where can I get demos that use custom plugin in ionic project. I googled it, but got noting useful.

Comment: Did you find the solution to this?

Comment: Yes,I got that error when running on browser,it works on simulator.

Comment: You must do this during Cordova document deviceready event.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for me plugin fired successfully by invoking it this way:

```
window.MyPlugin.pluginMethod(success, failure);
```

Interface of MyPlugin:

```
module.exports = {
    pluginMethod: function(success, failure) {
        cordova.exec(success, failure, "MyClass", "method", []);
    }
}
```

In case of problems with plugins in cordova/ionic, it's really good to log some objects (like window) and see whether plugins are there. Remember to log it when cordova/ionic is ready.